# No ejecutar un evento en cierto elemento de mi tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un evento en jQuery, el cual al hacer clic sobre cierta fila de una tabla ejecuta una acción, está acción se realiza de manera correcta pero lo que necesito es que cuando el usuario de clic en **cualquier fila** de la **columna #** de mi tabla, no se ejecute la acción. Mi duda es:

- ¿Cómo puedo realizar esto?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#list > tbody > tr').click(function(){
    console.log('He dado clic.');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped" id="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No uses selectors tan genéricos, mejor utiliza clases e id, de esa manera le pones a todas las celdas clickeables una clase, y a las no clickeables no se las pones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que la **Columna #** es la numero **1**, puedes usar el selector `td:not(:first-child)` que aplica el evento a todas la celdas excepto al primer hijo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#list > tbody > tr > td:not(:first-child)').click(function(){
    console.log('He dado clic.');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped" id="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Una contribución para el caso que se quiera especificar la posición de la columna: "td:not(:nth-child(1))", en este ejemplo caso la primera. Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

saludos puedes hacer de varias formas 
invocando la funcion en el tr ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped" id="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  onclick="clickRow(event);">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function clickRow(event){
alert("your click on specific row");
}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

aqui hice la prueba [prueba](https://jsfiddle.net/wjwuf9y8/4/)
espero te sirva

Comment: No es lo que busco. Sigue ejecutando el evento al dar clic sobre la primera columna de la fila. Y funcionaria si coloco el onclick en las columnas que las necesitara pero serían muchas y lo considero como una mala práctica.

Comment: podrias agregar una clase css y validar si hizo click en un tr que tenga dicha clase mediante javascript